# How to execute SQL in redshift with Airflow (version 1)

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to trigger a stored procedure in redshift from airflow?
Best scenario would be to not use a python operator, but I haven't found a reshift operator in airflow version < 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Airflow <2.1` there is no `RedShiftSqlOperator` because RedShift is compatible with PostgreSQL so you can just use `PostgresOperator`:

```
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
PostgresOperator(
        sql='SELECT * FROM my_table',
        postgres_conn_id='redshift_default',
        task_id='task',
    )
```

That said, in more recent versions (`Airflow >= 2.1`) since some users were struggling with this question as well (See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16544#issuecomment-864888396)) Airflow added `RedshiftSQLOperator` which is available in [Amazon provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/#description) version 2.4.0 :

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon>=2.4.0
```

Then you can use the operator as:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.redshift import RedshiftSQLOperator
    setup__task_create_table = RedshiftSQLOperator(
        task_id='task',
        redshift_conn_id="redshift_default"
        sql="SELECT * FROM my_table",
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! I did know the Airflow > 2.1 solution, but not the postgres solution.
Do I have to set the connection parameters in Airflow GUI or is there a way to pass it directly in the Operator?

Comment: @MiepMiep Connection must be set (whatever way you wish to do it). Can be done from the UI / CLI etc... In the operator you may override the defaults in the connection (if it allows)

Comment: good work-around for teams stuck in `aws mwaa 2.0.2`.